# 8 ball (i have solids) can I hit solid, stripe and then make a solid legally i.e.agood hit?

Tags: pool

8 Ball - when shooting 8 ball (I have solids) can I hit solid, stripe and then make a solid legally i.e. a good hit?

Answer (score 2):

For all the different rule sets I know, for example

- [EPA old rules](http://www.epa.org.uk/rules.php)
- [EPA Old World Rules](http://www.epa.org.uk/wrules.php)
- [EPA Current World Rules](http://www.epa.org.uk/images/rules/World%20Rules%202015.pdf)
- [IPA Blackball rules](http://ipapool.com/wp-content/uploads/IPA-Blackball-Rules.pdf) ... and many others

It is perfectly legal to carry out multiple cannon/plant shots as long as the object ball hit by the cue ball is a ball of your group (stripes or colour) and the ball potted is also a ball of your group.  The ball(s) within the middle of multiple cannons/plants are irrelevant.

The only thing to be careful of is if the rules you play stipulate that you must nominate a pocket and you pot the ball into a different pocket.

Answer (score 0):

That's legal. The ball you hit doesn't have to be the same ball that goes in the pocket.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14298)

Comment: It definitely does answer the question.Should I have just said "Yes"?

Comment: Please provide a source. Such short answers with no sources should be replaces with comments.